# Regex match multiline entries containing specified string

Tags: regex, recursion, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to collect statements that describe Rectangle 3 using regex (PCRE engine). This is part of a scraping project for a proprietary TGML-ish language. I

The input looks like this:

```
<Rectangle is 
    good>99$1</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    bad>99$2</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    ugly>3$3</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    fat>99$4</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    janky6789>99$5</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    34+35>99$6</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    <>>98$7</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    chicken>3$8</Rectangle>
<Rectangle 1 is 
    holy>97$9</Rectangle>
```

And the output to look like this:

```
<Rectangle is 
    ugly>3$3</Rectangle>
<Rectangle is 
    chicken>3$8</Rectangle>
```

I can get matches that contain Rectangle 3, but they also contain everything before it.

```
<Rectangle\X*?3\$\X*?<\/Rectangle>
```

It seems like there should be some kind of grouping or backtracking or recursion trick to this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Use `<Rectangle[^>]*>3\$[^<]*<\/Rectangle>`

Comment: What does `\X` mean?

Comment: @Bohemian `\X` matches any grapheme in PCRE. In Java, it is `\P{M}\p{M}*+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with negated character classes rather than lazy matching any graphemes with `\X*?`:

```php
<Rectangle[^>]*>3\$[^<]*<\/Rectangle>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qg8jkE/1).

Note that your `\X*?` matches any grapheme including `<`, `>`, line breaks, etc. and thus it will match as far as necessary to make the subsequent patterns match. Thus, with `[^>]*` and `[^<]*` you will be able to restict the chars the the pattern can match between fixed subpatterns.

*Details*

- `<Rectangle` - a literal string
- `[^>]*` - any zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>3\$` - a `>3$` string
- `[^<]*` - any zero or more chars other than `<`
- `<\/Rectangle>` - a `</Rectangle>` string.

Answer (score 0):

Just match whitespace, non-whitespace, then your target `>3\$`, ending with `.*` to capture the rest of the line:

```
<Rectangle is\s+\S+>3\$.*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Dw8nEqMDgA4KsH).